# How to get buttons the same design?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, button, elementor

At the moment, all buttons on my website have the same design (rounded, version 2 in screenshot). However, I have an iframe implemented on my website (data from external link), which contains buttons with a different style (square, version 1 in screenshot). Is there a way to change the style of the buttons from the iframe to the exact same style as my buttons? (through custom css for example?)

**The only differences between the buttons are the following:**

- Rounded vs. square-ish
- Thickness of text

**The hoover effect is the same.*

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz4AX.jpg

*Note: The website is built on Wordpress & Elementor (latest versions).*

Comment: As far as I'm aware, if you don't have access to the page the iframe is loading, you will have to use javascript to change its css: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe's source can't be modified, javascript is necessary to append your own style sheet:

```
<script>
  var yourCssFileWithRoundedButtons = "path/style.css";
  var yourIFrameId = "MyIFrame"


  var cssLink = document.createElement("link");
  cssLink.rel = "stylesheet"; 
  cssLink.type = "text/css"; 
  cssLink.href = yourCssFileWithRoundedButtons; 
  frames[yourIFrameId].document.head.appendChild(cssLink);
</script>
```

Keep in mind that you may be fighting with that external page's css, and you may have to be very specific in your selector to get your changes through

Comment: The Iframe's source can't be modified indeed, I only got access to the external link and that's it. Do I have to change anything in the coding you provided? Or can I just copy paste it?

Comment: I modified the code portion to specify what values you would need to change. Wherever you're getting your rounded button styles would go in the first value, and the iFrame's id attribute in the second value

Comment: Unless you've found a solution, I can revisit this now and take a look at your situation. You had a link to the site you were working with. May I see that link again?

Comment: Yeah, if that iframe isn't the same website there isn't much you can do unfortunately